# Using \nocite with multibib in MiKTeX

Tags: bibtex, multibib

I would like to create a LaTeX document with multiple bibliographies using the BibTeX and multibib packages. One of those bibliographies should contain all items in the related .bib file, even if they are not referred to in the text. But I can't get multibib's \nocite command to do this. I have tried to set up a simple test document outside of my work (which I will show below) to isolate the issue and have found that multibib's \nocite doesn't work in the most simple case.

I am using MiKTeX on Windows and I am editing and typesetting the documents in TeXworks using the default pdfLaTeX + MakeIndex + BibTeX typesetting mode. I created the following test case, with all files residing in the same folder:

**test.tex:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{bibone}{Bibliography 1}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\nocitebibone{*}
\bibliographystylebibone{apalike}
\bibliographybibone{bib1}
\end{document}
```

**bib1.bib:**

```
@book{texbook,
  author = {Donald E. Knuth},
  year = {1986},
  title = {The \TeX{} Book},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley Professional}
}
```

When typesetting test.tex in the manner described above, the resulting PDF only contains the text "Hello, world!" and not the bibliography entries. If I use the following test.tex instead:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{bib1}
\end{document}
```

I do get the desired result where both "Hello, world!" and the bibliography are printed into the final PDF. Running typesetting multiple times in TeXworks makes no difference. Maybe I'm missing something since I'm a novice LaTeX user and don't really understand the theory of its operation well.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: your document looks okay and it works for me. Check in the texworks options (edit->preferences->typesetting) if there is some --clean option in your processing which removes auxiliary files.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have tried this now, but unfortunately to no avail.

Comment: It does appear that typesetting my example works in an Overleaf project. I will have to dive into MiKTeX's settings ...